# How do I parse argument values in a SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
function userIn($u, $prof) {
   $db->query("INSERT INTO OnlineUser (Name, ProfilePicURL) VALUES '$u', '$prof';
   echo '$u is in'
}
```

How am I supposed to parse input values into the above SQL query? Simply $u and $prof? Or '($u)', ('$u')?

Comment: only problem is that?

Answer (score 0):

You missed `")` and enclose value in `()`

```
function userIn($u, $prof) {
   $db->query("INSERT INTO OnlineUser (Name, ProfilePicURL) VALUES ('$u', '$prof')");
   echo '$u is in';
}
```

Also use **Prepare statement** to prevent from SQL injections

Comment: How about in this? $db->query("DELETE FROM OnlineUser WHERE Name = '$u';") Do I also need to enclose value in parentheses?

Comment: No for delete no need check syntax for sql queries you will get it

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

For using variables in queries you use "Prepared statements". Depending on the type of your `$db` object it might look like this (for [Prepared statements in PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO
                          OnlineUser (Name, ProfilePicURL)
                      VALUES
                          (?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($u, $prof));
```

Comment: I heard the speed difference between the two is negligible. Is that true?